# I am confused about a claim in University Physics (Pearson) about wave motion

Tags: waves, coordinate-systems

This is an extract from the chapter, "Mathematical Description of a Wave", pg. no. 497.

> The wave disturbance travels from 
>   *x* = 0 to some point *x* to the right of the origin in an amount of time given by *x*/*v*, where *v* is the wave speed. So the motion of point *x* at time *t* is the same as the motion of point *x* = 0 at the earlier time *t* - *x*/*v*.

I couldn't figure out what this is supposed to mean. Anyone?

Comment: Which part of that quote  is confusing to you?

Answer (score 1):

So consider a function that depends on time and position via $$f(x, t) = g(x - v t).$$The minus sign is important here. At time $t=0$ you will see $$f(x, 0) = g(x).$$At time $t=1\text s$ this thing will move by a change in $x$ given by $\Delta x = v\cdot 1\text{ s}$ and you will see $$\begin{align}f(x, 1\text s)&=g(x -\Delta x)\\&= f(x - \Delta x, 0),\end{align}$$
in other words the function values you will see at $x$ at time $t$ will be the ones that you saw at $x - \Delta x$ at time $0$.

So those values have travelled *forwards* by a distance $\Delta x$.

This is really something that is very hard to remember, that the minus sign in $x - v t$ corresponds to forwards motion while the plus sign in $x + v t$ would correspond to backwards motion. Your brain wants to associate plus with forwards and minus with backwards, but that is wrong here, because the role of the minus sign is to say, “if we want to feed the exact same input into this function $g$ and thereby look at the same place on the wave, then when we increase $t$ we must also increase $x$ so that the difference between $x$ and $v t$ is constant.”

Answer (score 0):

The paragraph is saying that if you measure an amplitude variation versus time at the point $x = 0$, an observer at a different location, x, will see the same variation at a later time, with the time delay given by $x/v$.